# Can't echo the xml city name

Tags: php, xml

Hello everyone I've tried all possible ways to extract the name of a day from this xml, but haven't been successful..

```
<report>
<location city="Tukituki">
<day value="20130211" name="Sunday">
<symbol value="2" desc="Intervalos Nubosos"/>
<tempmin value="9"/>
<tempmax value="17"/>
<hour value="01:00">...</hour>
</day>
</location> 
</report>
```

I used `simplexml_load_file` whit the 'url' etc. And tried:

```
echo $xml->report->location[1]->city;
```

but it gives an error:  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post your xml itself please, not the `var_dump()` of SimpleXML.

Comment: and your code? What have you tried?

Comment: I'v tried echo $xml->report->location->day[0]->tempmin; but it gives the error: Trying to get property of non-object in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove **report** when you call your XML you are in this node.

```
echo $xml->location['city'];
```

And the attribute in the tag is called over the array notation.
If you have more locations then iterate over them.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Thanks... that was fast :)